# Error creating database on new storage in SQL Server 2008 R2 Failover Cluster

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, failover, storage

Via the Failover Cluster Manager, I recently added a new disk to an existing SQL Server 2008 R2 Cluster, running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

When attempting to create a database on this new storage, I get the following error:

```
Msg 5123, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'J:\DATA\mydatabase.mdf'.
Msg 1802, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

1. I can manually add a file to J:\data
2. The new storage can be moved between nodes without any errors
3. The SQL Server Service Account has full control over the entire J:\ drive
4. The SQL Server Service Account has full control over the J:\DATA 
   Here is a layout of the drive, you will notice that DATA is a seperate volume mounted inside J:\

[image]

Can someone please help me figure out why I am getting this error?

**Update**

From James, if I add a subdirectory to data, then the create database command works

```
CREATE DATABASE [MCO_DB] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'MYDATABASE_DB', FILENAME = N'J:\DATA\MYDATABASE\MYDATABASE_DB.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'MYDATABASE_DB_log', FILENAME = N'J:\TRN\MYDATABASE_DB_1.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

Comment: Is Data a mount point on J? If so I think you will need to set permissions inside the mount point to allow the SQL service account access.

Comment: Hi @JamesAnderson, yes the service account has full control over the mount point.

Comment: Have you tried tracing sqlservr.exe with ProcMon? Maybe some more info is available there.

Comment: So if you look at a file/folder in the 'data' mount point does the sql account have the access you expect?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/836873

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan, yes I tried that as well, the default directory for data and trn are correct.

Comment: You're attempting to create the file in the route of 'Data'. Does it work if you use something like `J:\DATA\mydatabase\mydatabase.mdf` ?

Comment: @JamesAnderson, yes I can, we are on the right path

Comment: I think it was because you need admin rights to create a file in the route of a drive and a mount point is seen as a drive

Comment: @JamesAnderson, but I have another instance on the same cluster that can write to its own data mount point.

Comment: Is it writing to the route of that mount point? Different service account?

Comment: @JamesAnderson, yes it is writing to that mount point, same service account for all instances

Comment: I can only think there must be a difference in permissions in or on those mount points. :(

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan this only applies if you are not specifying the the filenames in the create database statement. In the statement provided the filename is provided so the default database path in the registry is ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the System Volume Information Folder which is a hidden folder at the root of this volume.

[image]

On other volumes on the same machine, this protected volume was accessible after being made visible in Folder Options

[image]

I could not however access the System Volume Information folder of the DATA directory that I was attempting to create databases in.

**Steps taken to resolve by our Windows Admin**

1. A new Drive letter T: was created
2. The contents of the J: drive was copied into it
3. The J: Drive was destroyed and the T: drive was changed to the J: drive in Windows.

After which, I was able to create databases normally.

Thanks to @jamesanderson for sending me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Operating system error 5 is a simple `Access is denied` you can always check those errors in the command prompt `net helpmsg 5`.

Now Volume mount points are sometimes a bother. In Windows server 2000 the calcs.exe [had an error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/237701) and could not set the permissions on the underlying drive and the only way to do it was to mount the volume using a drive letter, set permissions on the root folder and then create a mountpoint.

Later versions of windows should be able set the permissions on the mountpoint by using the /M switch so that

> cacls j:\data /g DOMAIN\ACCOUNT:f /M /E

Will grant the domain\account full permissions on the root of the drive mounted at j:\data, I still haven't leard to do this with `icacls.exe` and a comment how to do so will be well appriciated.

As you have found out creating a subfolder on the mount point makes it possible for you to create an accesslist for that folder but there still seem to be issues with setting permissions on the root folder of the drive using the GUI.

Usually I dont bother with the calcs command and if I need to set permissions on the root I'll add a driveletter, set the permissions using the GUI and then remove the drive letter.